# PHPStorm recognizing variable not included in PHP file

Tags: phpstorm

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Create a new project.
2. Create a PHP file named `a.php` with the following contents: `<?php $customerName = 'Mary';`
3. Create another PHP file named `b.php` with the following contents: `<?php echo $customerName;`

What is the expected result?
Since `a.php` is not included in `b.php`, the IDE should warning the user about the undefined variable `$customerName`.

What happens instead?
The IDE accepts the variable as if `a.php` were included in `b.php`.

PHPStorm version is 6.0.2.

Comment: show a small representative sample of the code in question. screenshots are useless.

Comment: `Settings | Inspections | PHP | Undefined | Undefined variable` -- play with inspection settings a tiny bit.

Comment: rewriten the post to better explain the problem.

Comment: I think that's because there's no practical way of knowing whether the file in included or not. It may have been autoloaded before, or they may both be included in some third file. Also, if your rely on file scoping, you're doing it wrong. That's why functions and classes and *Scope* in general were made.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I'm not really taking that route, but this is something that caught my attention and I got a bit worried about the IDE not being able to get it right. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Alexandre, as the option to ignore 'includes' and 'requires' didn't do the trick, I reported the issue as a new ticket to the PhpStorm bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18854

Comment: Again, thanks for your help, Maxim!